# Cassandra CQL: How to do WHERE-like queries on dynamic columns?

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql, cql3, cassandra-cli

Consider the following simple table in Cassandra, with some values inserted via CQL3:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (  
  id varchar,  
  name varchar,  
  value varchar,  
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name));

INSERT INTO sometable (id, name, value) VALUES ('Mary', 'Favorite Color', 'Red');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, name, value) VALUES ('George', 'Favorite Color', 'Green');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, name, value) VALUES ('Bob', 'Favorite Color', 'Red');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, name, value) VALUES ('Mary', 'Phone', '555-1234');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, name, value) VALUES ('George', 'Phone', '555-1212');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, name, value) VALUES ('Bob', 'Email', 'bob@bob.com');
```

Let's say we want to get the phone numbers of everyone whose favorite color is red. For example, something like:

```
SELECT 'Phone' FROM sometable WHERE 'Favorite Color' = 'Red';
```

The only way I can think of actually doing this would be to select the names of all columns of interest, and then do the filtering client-side:

```
SELECT name, value from sometable WHERE name IN ('Favorite Color', 'Phone') allow filtering;
```

Is there a way to filter on dynamic column values in CQL, or in any other Cassandra API?

Answer (score 1):

Secondary indexes would allow you to search on different fields that the one which are in the partition key / clustering key. You can find some useful documentation there:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/ddl/indexes

Be sure to read the **When to Use Secondary Indexes** / **When Not to Use Secondary Indexes** clauses.
Taking the time to think how you'll query your *column families* might be the more important thing to do when you're using Cassandra, this, and being sure that you *need* Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this quite addresses my question. I'm looking to search on a field which is in the clustering key.